# Bandsaw Blade Too Short

Tags: bandsaw

I can't fit my blade on my bandsaw (Laguna 18BX). I have lowered the top wheel through releasing tension both through bottoming out the blade guide adjustment hand wheel and the quick-release blade tension lever and I can't get my 145" blade to fit.

I even used a clamp to try and pull the wheel down. Things are well made, but I'm at a total loss.

Comment: Did you look at the Owners Manual?  You might consider contacting Laguna support.  Perhaps the unit is assembled improperly or you have an incorrect blade.

Comment: Have you compared new blade to old? Or did you chop the old one up already?

Comment: That's a _nice_ band saw (you have my envy)! Is this brand new and the factory supplied blade doesn't fit, or is this a replacement blade? If it's brand new, it might, as painful as it sounds, be a manufacturing defect. If it's old, maybe the blade was mismarked as 145" when it's actually shorter (the [docs](https://860860.app.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=1562109&c=860860&h=b437fd45307cd2b17e19&_xt=.pdf) say a minimum of 143-3/4").

Comment: Using a clamp to pull on parts of a $2,000 saw is highly dubious, and may have expensive consequences. RtM and/or call support, indeed.

Comment: You indicated that you tried to pull "the" wheel "down". Which wheel is "the" wheel, and are you sure it's supposed to go down, not up?

Comment: I would measure the blade in my experience a most high end bandsaws can handle a fair difference in blade length, they may have shipped the wrong one.

Comment: Yes. Read the manual and called tech support today. They were closed on the weekend and I thought someone here may have a technique I’m missing